# 'D3DRS_SEPARATEDESTALPHAENABLE' : undeclared identifier - even though it's mentioned in the DirectX comments?

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, hlsl

In d3d9types.h in the _D3DRENDERSTATETYPE struct the last 3 types are:

```
D3DRS_SRCBLENDALPHA             = 207,  /* SRC blend factor for the alpha channel when D3DRS_SEPARATEDESTALPHAENABLE is TRUE */
D3DRS_DESTBLENDALPHA            = 208,  /* DST blend factor for the alpha channel when D3DRS_SEPARATEDESTALPHAENABLE is TRUE */
D3DRS_BLENDOPALPHA              = 209,  /* Blending operation for the alpha channel when D3DRS_SEPARATEDESTALPHAENABLE is TRUE */
```

Notice it mentions that these will be used if 'D3DRS_SEPARATEDESTALPHAENABLE is TRUE', however there is no D3DRS_SEPARATEDESTALPHAENABLE in the struct whatsoever. The closest thing seems to be: "D3DRS_SEPARATEALPHABLENDENABLE" but I'm not at all sure if this is the same thing.

So i was just wondering what should be set to true for those last three renderstates to actually work (if anything?), I strongly think it's D3DRS_SEPARATEALPHABLENDENABLE but would like someone to please confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, D3DRS_SEPARATEALPHABLENDENABLE.  Looks like a typo in the comments.

From the DXSDK:

> D3DRS_SRCBLENDALPHA
>
> One member of the D3DBLEND enumerated
>   type. This value is ignored unless
>   D3DRS_SEPARATEALPHABLENDENABLE is
>   true. The default value is
>   D3DBLEND_ONE.
>
> D3DRS_DESTBLENDALPHA
>
> One member of the D3DBLEND enumerated
>   type. This value is ignored unless
>   D3DRS_SEPARATEALPHABLENDENABLE is
>   true. The default value is
>   D3DBLEND_ZERO.
>
> D3DRS_BLENDOPALPHA
>
> Value used to select the arithmetic
>   operation applied to separate alpha
>   blending when the render state,
>   D3DRS_SEPARATEALPHABLENDENABLE, is set
>   to TRUE.
>
> Valid values are defined by the
>   D3DBLENDOP enumerated type. The
>   default value is D3DBLENDOP_ADD.  If
>   the D3DPMISCCAPS_BLENDOP device
>   capability is not supported, then
>   D3DBLENDOP_ADD is performed. See
>   D3DPMISCCAPS.